# MySQL on event schedule

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, syntax-error

I'm getting the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'END' at line 7

```
DELIMITER$$
CREATE EVENT myevs
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY

DO 
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO ww SELECT * FROM fff WHERE dates = NOW()
   DELETE FROM fff where dates = NOW()
END$$

DELIMITER;
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing the terminating `;` for each of the `INSERT,DELETE` statements. That's the reason for setting the alternative `$$` delimiter -- those statements need to be separated by `;`. The syntax error is ambiguously targeting `END` though, so I'm not certain that is the only problem you have here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing semicolons (`;`) at the end of the `insert` and `delete` statements:

```
DELIMITER$$
CREATE EVENT myevs
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY

DO 
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO ww SELECT * FROM fff WHERE dates = NOW();
   -- Here --------------------------------------------^

   DELETE FROM fff where dates = NOW();
   -- And here -----------------------^
END$$

DELIMITER;
```